# How to update a range of an XMl file tag?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

My problem is I don't know How to update a XML file. In the following XML file I want to include some tags inside another tag which are already exist in the file.
**My XML file is as following: **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <PayrunDetails>
        <PayrunNumber>000777</PayrunNumber>
    </PayrunDetails>
    <PayLocation>
        <LocationCode>ACT</LocationCode>
        <LocationDescription>ACT</LocationDescription>
        <CompanyDetails>
            <CName>APPLE Limited</CName>
            <Payslip>
                <StaffNumber>12345</StaffNumber>
                <PayDetails>
                    <AmountGross>9999</AmountGross>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType>SALARY</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>1999</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>10616</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType>SALARY</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>7305</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>76703</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                </PayDetails>
            </Payslip>
        </CompanyDetails>
    </PayLocation>
</root>
```

**My desired output file is as following:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <PayrunDetails>
        <PayrunNumber>000777</PayrunNumber>
    </PayrunDetails>
    <PayLocation>
        <LocationCode>ACT</LocationCode>
        <LocationDescription>ACT</LocationDescription>
        <CompanyDetails>
            <CName>APPLE Limited</CName>
            <Payslip>
                <StaffNumber>12345</StaffNumber>
                <PayDetails>
                    <AmountGross>9999</AmountGross>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType ID="SALARY">
                            <Amount>1999</Amount>
                            <YTDAmount>10616</YTDAmount>
                        </ComponentType>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType ID="TAX">
                            <Amount>7305</Amount>
                            <YTDAmount>76703</YTDAmount>
                        </ComponentType>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                </PayDetails>
            </Payslip>
        </CompanyDetails>
    </PayLocation>
</root>
```

In the above desired file you will find that ComponentType tag has included the rest of the tags exist inside the ComponentDetails tag.

For the above said problem I want to use XSLT but I don't know what code should I write to get the solution.
I'm fairly new to XSLT so please excuse the potential novice question. Any guidance would be appreciated here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read up on the i[dentity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) in XSLT, which involves this template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(If you could use XSLT 3.0, you could just write `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` instead)

This will copy across all your nodes and attributes as-is, which in your case gets you almost there.

There are a number of ways you could the transform of the nodes you want. One way is to match the `ComponentDetails` tag, to create a new `ComponentType` in the output, along with code to select the other child nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="ComponentDetails">
  <xsl:copy>
      <ComponentType ID="{ComponentType}">
          <xsl:apply-templates />
      </ComponentType>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This makes use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) to create the `ID` attribute.

Note that `<xsl:apply-templates />` is short-hand for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />` and so this will still select the existing `ComponentType` element in the input document, which will then be matched by the identity template. To stop `ComponentType` being output twice, you need to add a template to match and ignore it.

```
<xsl:template match="ComponentType" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ComponentDetails">
    <xsl:copy>
        <ComponentType ID="{ComponentType}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ComponentType>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ComponentType" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim C for understanding my problem and providing me a correct solution, I have tested it on my sample data and if I face any issue on production data then I'll disturb u again ;)